# Xpath how to grab divs in order by specifying their classes or names

Tags: xpath

I am trying to grab content from pages that are structured like the one below, but some of the pages have different amounts of paragraphs and headers. So the one below has a header after the fourth paragraph, sometimes this could be after the second and so on. How do I grab all the content in order each time without specifying exact divs? I tried this:

//*[@id="tab_info"]/p[16]

It does work but then I cannot work out from the Xpath code which the titles are on the CSV without doing manual work. I think I need "contains" perhaps? This doesn't seem to be working for me:

//*[@id="tab_info"]/p[1][contains(.,strong)]

```
<div id="tab_info" class="tab_content active">
                <h2>Information</h2>
    <p><strong>This Is The Main Title</strong></p>
        <p>This is a content div.</p>
        <p><strong>This is Subtitle 1</strong></p>
        <p>This is the second paragraph</p>
        <p>This is the third paragraph</p>
        <p>This is the fourth paragraph</p>
    <p><strong>This is Subtitle 2</strong></p>
        <p>This is the fifth paragraph.</p>
        <p>This is the sixth paragraph.</p>
        <p><strong>This is Subtitle 3</strong></p>
       <p>This is the seventh paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: What is desired output? Which element(s) exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to grab those `p` elements that have a `strong` child, then you might try

```
//div[@id="tab_info"]/p[strong]
```